# Colorize inside an image in Insscape (SVG)

Tags: color, svg

ALL,

I made a little SVG transparent image in Inkscape, which shows a piece of paper and a little magnifying glass.

Unfortunately I didn't realize that a piece of paper has to be white and not transparent.

Could someone please explain how to colorize inside the image?

TIA!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="SVGRoot" width="16px" height="16px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
 <metadata>
  <rdf:RDF>
   <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
    <dc:title/>
   </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
 </metadata>
 <g stroke="#000">
  <g fill="none" stroke-width="1px">
   <path d="m0 555c0.16838 0.17165 0.33892 0.34121 0.50514 0.51495 0.013494 0.0141 0 0.11841 0 0.14095 0 0.0791-0.001269 0.16127-0.032822 0.22815-0.036464 0.0773 0.040216 0.29687 0 0.36618-0.063468 0.10938 0.001153 0.24025-0.037423 0.35552-0.052308 0.15631-0.019632 0.36972-0.019632 0.53635v0.99831c0 0.13124-0.052048 0.6208-0.016411 0.71588 0.003248 9e-3 0.015139 0.0115 0.019632 0.0196 0.034599 0.0623-0.034956 0.18272 0 0.24479 0.049593 0.088 0.018098 0.4991 0.018098 0.63558 0 0.2133-0.035515 0.77696 0.03704 0.92431 0.026933 0.0547-0.005654 0.44572-0.019632 0.5125-0.0305 0.14571 0 0.36912 0 0.52132 0 0.20606-0.019632 0.40327-0.019632 0.60751 0 0.22789-0.019632 0.44283-0.019632 0.67194v0.1615c0 0.0327 0.02841 0.11413 0 0.098-0.14088-0.07994-0.27648-0.16888-0.41472-0.25334"/>
   <path d="m1 555c-0.11319-0.0639-0.22807-0.12485-0.33957-0.19164-0.005614-3e-3 0.013088 0 0.019632 0 0.03705 0 0.060897-2e-3 0.091258-0.017 0.043991-0.022 0.19575-0.11078 0.22929-0.14432 0.055267-0.0553 0.10745-0.0744 0.16787-0.11979 0.091385-0.0687 0.17657-0.15122 0.2717-0.21464 0.031349-0.0209 0.066126-0.0273 0.093252-0.0544 0.035357-0.0354 0.10225-0.0587 0.14509-0.0824 0.0877-0.0486 0.16271-0.11789 0.25552-0.1487 0.064814-0.0215 0.12317-0.043 0.18321-0.0728 0.033463-0.0166 0.098393-7e-3 0.13528-0.0196 0.028598-9e-3 0.0704-0.0592 0.096319-0.0768 0.058632-0.04 0.13534-0.0506 0.19463-0.0903 0.01933-0.0129 0.030915-0.0375 0.050307-0.0503 0.04132-0.0272 0.095051-0.0386 0.13581-0.0589 0.043816-0.0219 0.22308-0.15301 0.24402-0.19241 0.040304-0.0758 0.041905-0.18933 0.01089-0.27561-0.019701-0.05493 0.016817-0.13811 0.01549-0.19039"/>
   <path d="m1 564c-0.006314-0.0287 0.00971-0.0923-0.018942-0.086-0.028655 6e-3 -8.1092e-4 0.0643 0.018942 0.086 0.029455 0.0324 0.077829 0.0401 0.11572 0.062 0.016698 0.01 0.10761 0.11448 0.11641 0.13075 0.00233 4e-3 0 0.01 0 0.0147 0.00654 0.0127 0.01164 0.0262 0.019632 0.038 0.019606 0.029 0.43616 0.513 0.44701 0.51901 0.00951 5e-3 0.027423-5e-3 0.037193 0 0.01499 7e-3 0.03924 0.054 0.050767 0.0627 0.080555 0.06108 0.1099 0.0843 0.21327 0.17284"/>
   <path d="m12 554c0.13382-0.15941 0.27044-0.3165 0.40146-0.47822 0.0029-4e-3 -0.0094 0-0.01403 0h-0.07561c-0.03639 0-0.0485-0.0103-0.07661-0.0196-0.04107-0.0137-0.09582 0.0137-0.13689 0-0.22426-0.0747-0.54478-0.0899-0.77584-0.0272-0.03162 9e-3 -0.07313-0.0104-0.10422 0-0.05641 0.0188-0.1108 0.0367-0.17178 0.0367-0.07851 0-0.15596 0.0194-0.23773 0.0194-0.14768 0-0.65722-0.0382-0.77247 0.0194-0.02428 0.0121-0.070368-9e-3 -0.095705 0-0.00877 3e-3 -0.010657 0.0174-0.019632 0.0196-0.061398 0.0154-0.15254 0-0.21495 0-0.066934 0-0.5086 0.0229-0.5694 0-0.038085-0.0143-0.052384-0.0194-0.093712-0.0194h-1.5146c-0.022131 0-0.57886 0.0179-0.61166 0-0.10747-0.0587-0.29004-0.064-0.41656-0.0961-0.095526-0.0243-0.23219 0-0.3309 0-0.05355 0-0.037951 7.8e-4 -0.077531-0.0194-0.054435-0.0278-0.19794 0-0.26196 0-0.082752 0-0.21721 6e-3 -0.28727-0.0279-0.042384-0.0208-0.11675 0.0149-0.1615 0-0.048488-0.0162-0.091164-0.0213-0.13857-0.0388-0.043042-0.0159-0.7417-0.0168-0.80844 0-0.045342 0.0114-0.088744 0.0324-0.13689 0.0393-0.099852 0.0143-0.21169 0-0.31396 0-0.19661 0-0.37639 0.0208-0.56143-0.0314-0.18131-0.05115-0.2807-0.2513-0.42156-0.37638"/>
   <path d="m13 555c-0.28343-0.13868 0.36745-0.31205 0.45851-0.176 0.04351 0.065 0.03767 0.15131 0.07278 0.21181 0.02452 0.0423-1e-3 0.0925 0.0194 0.13321 0.07691 0.15351-0.0109 0.51019 0.0194 0.69202 0.01725 0.10352 0.03341 0.21249 0.0589 0.31411 0.02256 0.09 0.0042 0.20487 0.03926 0.3102 0.02923 0.0877 0 0.24093 0 0.33375v0.70728c0 0.19512 0.03978 0.58058-0.01963 0.75813-0.02537 0.0758 0 0.37978 0 0.48443v1.1811c0 0.21245 0.03839 0.47145-0.03267 0.6694-0.01391 0.0388 0 0.113 0 0.15291 0 0.11499 0.02877 0.64831 0 0.73313-0.05039 0.14856 0.02031 0.4355-0.01933 0.53735-0.03951 0.10151-0.0084 0.23321-0.05483 0.32438-0.02238 0.044 0.02406 0.12536 0 0.16826-0.04227 0.0754-0.02684 0.51474-0.02684 0.62484 0 0.45067 0.02817 0.91028-0.0783 1.3374-0.01067 0.0428 0.01076 0.0936 0 0.13642-0.01834 0.0729-0.03405 0.2517-0.05859 0.29924-0.02626 0.0509 0.04202 0.1937 0.05476 0.24225 0.01371 0.0523-0.01711 0.11949 0 0.17063 0.0047 0.014 0.02627 0.0361 0.01963 0.056-0.0083 0.0249-0.03116-5e-3 -0.03597-0.01-0.13865-0.13089-0.27765-0.26152-0.41648-0.39232"/>
   <path d="m13 565c-0.03474 0.15358-0.06363 0.3086-0.10422 0.46074-4.81e-4 2e-3 -0.04529 0-0.05046 0-0.02328 0-0.09514 0.0181-0.11794 0.0297-0.04147 0.0211-0.11222-0.018-0.15537 0-0.041 0.0171-0.06102 0.0187-0.10568 0.0187-0.07705 0-0.43943 0.0365-0.48781 0.01-0.02143-0.0118-0.1133-0.0442-0.14088-0.0265-0.06963 0.0445-0.39676 0.0494-0.46273 0.0204-0.0667-0.0293-0.5435 0-0.66411 0h-0.64862c-0.01286 0-0.03696-0.0196-0.03796-7e-3 -0.012807 0.16437-0.016155 0.32931-0.024233 0.49396"/>
   <path d="m8 566c0.080879-0.14174 0.1666-0.28083 0.24264-0.42523 2.75e-4 -5.2e-4 -0.13908 0.0196-0.15422 0.0196-0.14976 0 0.015487-9e-3 -0.098159 0.0196-0.11392 0.0285-0.273 0-0.39195 0-0.12188 0-0.2373 0.0103-0.35192 0.039-0.11467 0.0288-0.32456 0-0.44778 0-0.10713 0-0.47024-0.0288-0.55636 0-0.054572 0.0183-0.075854 0.0196-0.13689 0.0196-0.36533 0-0.71515 0.0161-1.0557-0.0913-0.072138-0.0228-0.15232-0.0145-0.22531-0.039-0.040897-0.0137-0.095617 0.0137-0.1365 0-0.082559-0.0277-0.16917-0.0355-0.25951-0.0587-0.042293-0.0109-0.092763 0.0106-0.13512 0-0.028387-7e-3 -0.050778-0.03-0.078528-0.0393-0.047166-0.0158-0.10807 0.0121-0.15652 0-0.1209-0.0302-0.2545-0.0196-0.38236-0.0196-0.045302 0-0.057683-8e-3 -0.092485-0.0194-0.089263-0.0295-0.57209 0-0.7089 0-0.052457 0-0.1245-0.0129-0.17569 0-0.10265 0.0258-0.20963 0.0612-0.31334 0.0785-0.076465 0.0127-0.15973 7.3e-4 -0.23512 0.0196-0.025815 6e-3 -0.1793 0.039-0.17929 0.039 0.0068322 0.15288 0.019325 0.30518 0.028988 0.45763"/>
   <path d="m14 566 2 1.7999"/>
   <path d="m1 556c-0.023722 0.0636-0.050859 0.12598-0.071166 0.19072-0.005447 0.0174 0.036401 0 0.054601 0h0.15169c0.040177 0 0.047214 5e-3 0.085046 0.0184 0.021456 8e-3 0.37311 0.0178 0.42247 0.0178 0.037197 0-0.00805-4e-3 0.035506 0.0194 0.02656 0.0142 0.10249 0 0.13206 0 0.01622 0 0.043018 0.0111 0.056979 0.0176 0.00671 3e-3 0.01239 0.0223 0.015721 0.0157 0.045429-0.09022 0.078067-0.18639 0.1171-0.27962"/>
   <path d="m2 557c0.05864 0.0635 0.11456 0.12962 0.17592 0.19049 0.010746 0.0107 0.070383 0 0.089954 0 0.099195 0 0.23046-0.0253 0.326 0 0.040366 0.0107 0.073608 0.0284 0.11595 0.0393 0.046103 0.0119 0.10137-9e-3 0.14801 0 0.10309 0.0206 0.20589 0.0221 0.3092 0.0393 0.26094 0.0435 0.53196 0.0931 0.80123 0.0393 0.072531-0.0145 0.14228-1e-3 0.21595-0.0196 0.072111-0.0181 0.16019 0.0105 0.23359 0 0.064766-9e-3 0.13032-0.0283 0.19578-0.0393 0.22872-0.0381 0.45972 0.0578 0.6885 0.0196 0.30584-0.051 0.66474-0.0345 0.97508 0 0.093557 0.0104 0.20338-0.0228 0.29448 0 0.29639 0.0741 0.60652 0.0728 0.91097 0.10046 0.11484 0.0104 0.23947-0.019 0.35337 0 0.097461 0.0162 0.19411 0.0514 0.29448 0.0589 0.1699 0.0127 0.34663 3e-3 0.51656 0.0196 0.19468 0.0195 0.01923 0.0117 0.15706 0.0393 0.073484 0.0147 0.18004 0 0.25445 0h1.1561c0.15463 0 0.31937 0.0171 0.46641-0.0196 0.07772-0.0194 0.1642 0.0208 0.23351-0.0178 0.07641-0.0425 0.50601 0.0468 0.63351-0.0314 0.19964-0.12272-0.14715 0.1583 0.45391-0.41855"/>
   <path d="m1 559c0.042817 0.10813 0.080404 0.21848 0.12845 0.32439 0.00189 4e-3 0.11308 0 0.15736 0 0.08764 0 0.14892 2.3e-4 0.22469 0.0364 0.036793 0.0176 0.082964 4.2e-4 0.12094 0.0194 0.043061 0.0215 0.16444 0 0.21396 0 0.13681 2e-5 0.10051-0.25452 0.1546-0.38019"/>
   <path d="m2 560c0.09862 0.0946 0.18904 0.19848 0.29586 0.28367 0.010545 8e-3 0.022808-0.0149 0.035506-0.0194 0.06012-0.0215 0.16761 0 0.23252 0 0.2965 0 0.75069 0.0476 1.0113-0.0393 0.093395-0.0311 0.27361 0.01 0.39072-0.0196 0.14451-0.0361 0.48051 0.0178 0.60276 0.0589 0.049344 0.0166 0.12239 6e-3 0.17569 0.0196 0.089558 0.0224 0.21968 0 0.31242 0h0.78428c0.08432 0 0.15476 6e-3 0.23558 0.0196 0.17989 0.03 0.53213 0 0.7227 0 0.10071 0 0.21315 0.0142 0.31288 0 0.42692-0.061 0.83268-0.11749 1.2691-0.11749 0.11331 0 0.31205-0.0271 0.41802 0 0.060704 0.0155 0.11765 0.0246 0.17646 0.0393 0.042447 0.0106 0.096087-0.0138 0.13742 0 0.041698 0.0139 0.092392 0.0276 0.14018 0.0363 0.11144 0.0203 0.22313-0.0174 0.33129 0.0193 0.093497 0.0318 0.38223-0.0383 0.45115 0 0.13553 0.0754 0.29118 0.0687 0.4207 0.13328 0.02962 0.0148 0.07786 2e-3 0.10928 0.0157 0.06231 0.0279 0.1625-0.0169 0.22914 0 0.03977 0.0101 0.1049 0.0378 0.14471 0.0378 0.18463 0 0.44561 0.0408 0.60307-0.0357 0.0459-0.0223 0.11278 0.0108 0.15951-0.0135 0.01657-9e-3 0.13324 0.0144 0.13903 0 0.055566-0.13839 0.10583-0.27894 0.15874-0.41846"/>
   <path d="m1 562c-0.04591 0.0693-0.095498 0.13625-0.13773 0.20782-0.002113 4e-3 0.059159 2e-3 0.10652 0.0181 0.076061 0.0253 0.17127 0.0321 0.25008 0.0321 0.042487 0-0.00897-4e-3 0.0375 0.0193 0.040347 0.0205 0.15357 6e-3 0.21442 0.0381 0.032185 0.0168 0.090527-0.0167 0.12278 0 0.062333 0.0323 0.35622 0.0752 0.43183 0.0752 0.21215 0 0.41433 0.0119 0.61511-0.038 0.042412-0.0105 0.09183 9e-3 0.13474 0 0.098223-0.0197 0.022394-0.0136 0.098159-0.0393 0.076231-0.0258 0.38875 0 0.48972 0 0.06407 0 0.4278 4e-3 0.45529 0.018 0.04031 0.0202 0.056351 0.0372 0.1036 0.0372 0.010155 0-0.027297 0.0273-0.025 0.0174 0.03012-0.12966 0.068661-0.25726 0.10299-0.38592"/>
   <path d="m4 563c0.075 0.12467 0.14541 0.25221 0.225 0.374 0.01039 0.0159 0.037986 0 0.056979 0h1.0772c0.062456 0 0.27437 0.0243 0.32293 0 0.080211-0.0401 0.19375-0.0283 0.28397-0.0589 0.084111-0.0285 0.22417 0.0405 0.30268 0 0.054014-0.0279 0.12118-0.0381 0.1875-0.0381 0.045567 0-0.00949 5e-3 0.038727-0.0193 0.047419-0.0235 0.11739 0.0101 0.16595-0.0148 0.034472-0.0177 0.090512 0.0161 0.12784 0.0161 0.020965 0 0.15003 8e-3 0.1523 0 0.024626-0.08506 0.039263-0.17268 0.058895-0.259"/>
   <path d="m8 563c0.04862 0.14036 0.093416 0.28211 0.14586 0.42109 0.00571 0.0151 0.032892-4e-3 0.048543 0 0.085002 0.0223 0.00806 0.0196 0.057285 0.0196 0.06512 0 0.16199 0.0229 0.2306 0.0315 0.045582 6e-3 0.11288-0.0148 0.15683 0 0.039879 0.0134 0.055096 0.0196 0.097623 0.0196 0.070648 0 0.20923 9.4e-4 0.20936 0 0.022594-0.1633 0.035941-0.32783 0.053911-0.49179"/>
   <path d="m0.66751 3.559 0.022119 9.441"/>
   <path d="m0.66751 3.559 1.3325-1.559"/>
   <path d="m2 1.5595c11-0.19828 11-0.16499 11-0.16499"/>
   <path d="m16 16-2-2z"/>
   <path d="m13.246 14 0.0122-12z"/>
   <path d="m1 12.481c1-0.0076 1-0.0012 1-0.0012"/>
   <path d="m2 13.495c5 0.0012 5 0.06266 5 0.06266"/>
   <path d="M 12.671521,13.415696 C 9,13.418451 9,13.426086 9,13.426086"/>
   <path d="m1 5.5231c1 0.013303 1 0.013303 0 0z"/>
   <path d="m2.4536 6.4033 8.5464-0.058564"/>
   <path d="m1 7.5707 1-0.032903"/>
   <path d="m2.5532 8.4445 8.4468-0.081785"/>
   <path d="m1 10.401 2-0.03227"/>
   <path d="m4 11.392 2.7978 0.02849z"/>
   <path d="m8 11.327c3 0.03605 3 0.03605 3 0.03605"/>
  </g>
  <circle cx="12.793" cy="12.772" rx="1.7931" ry="1.7716" fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
  <path d="m12.433 13.978c-0.21352-0.06358-0.34961-0.14325-0.51992-0.30436-0.2697-0.25514-0.39732-0.54801-0.39563-0.90792 2e-3 -0.42979 0.19932-0.79202 0.56439-1.0362 0.22634-0.15138 0.42328-0.20927 0.71388-0.20984 0.20112-3.9e-4 0.25301 0.0069 0.39275 0.055 0.66471 0.22892 1.0162 0.87713 0.83696 1.5437-0.07893 0.29358-0.36149 0.63089-0.64533 0.77038-0.08312 0.04085-0.21008 0.08812-0.28212 0.10505-0.19463 0.04573-0.48123 0.03893-0.66499-0.01579z" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width=".54"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if you include the SVG here for us to look at

Comment: @ZachSaucier, added.

Comment: BTW, its not possible to upload the SVG image, so I placed it inline...

Comment: I think the problem is that it's not a very well constructed SVG image. The "paper" isn't actually a rectangle, it's a collection of various paths - [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ9HB.png) Adding a fill to open, disjointed, path segments rarely has the appearance one wants.

Comment: @Scott, understood. So my best bet is to redo the image by making the rectangle and then it will be easier?

Comment: Yes. As an actual rectangle you can fill it and it will be much more "stable" as an SVG image. In addition, you really *can't* "fill" the paper you currently have. You'd *have* to create a closed shape to add a fill.. so you may as well draw an actual rectangle for the paper.

Comment: @Scott, ok, thx

Comment: @Scott, I just realized that the paper is not a perfect square. The top left corner is cut-off. Is it possible to make is as such? If yes - could you give me instructions?

Comment: I'm not an Inkscape user, sorry. (I prefer Illustrator) It's a relatively easy thing to do.. but I'm just not familiar with Inkscape tools. You can post a new question about that specific aspect, someone will answer.